# Call model method with multiple arguments on django template

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class InflacConstraint(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name = 'constraints', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
    constraint_type = models.CharField(choices = CONSTRAINT_CHOICES, max_length = 32)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ExtraField, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    value = models.FloatField()

    def calc(self, vacations = False, external = False):
        return self.task.calc(self.date_from, self.date_to, vacations = vacations, external = external)
```

If calc() had no parameters, i could just call `object.calc` inside a django template with no problems.

How would one call `object.calc(vacations = True, external = True)` inside the django template?

Comment: That is not possible. But, you can define your own [***custom tag/filter***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to get the desired result.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that path, but guess i'll have to do it.

Thanks